# Pass id parameter in fetch query (ReactJS)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

I am new in javscript development, and I have some trouble with passing id parameter in query URL. 
I am passing ID value in body now, which is not right, I guess in REST approach.

How can I pass `Id: event.target.DepartmentId.value,` into URL like `https://localhost:5001/api/departments/{id}` ?

```js
handleSubmit(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    fetch("https://localhost:5001/api/departments/", {
        method: "PUT",
        headers:{
            "Accept":"application/json",
            "Content-Type":"application/json",
            "Origin": "*"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            Id: event.target.DepartmentId.value,
            Name: event.target.DepartmentName.value
        })
    })
    .then(res=>res.json())
    .then((result)=>
    {
        this.setState({snackbaropen: true, snackbarmsg: "Edited successfully!"})
        
    },
    (error) =>{
        this.setState({snackbaropen: true, snackbarmsg: "failed"})
    }
    )
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You can build up your URI as you want. For example "https://localhost:5001/api/departments/" + event.target.DepartmentId.value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked. And the literals didn't.

```
  localhost:5001/api/departments" + event.target.DepartmentId.value
```

Answer (score 2):

you should use params

and query params at the server side

```
   `https://localhost:5001/api/departments/?id=${id}`
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use js template literal like this:

```js
handleSubmit(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    fetch(`https://localhost:5001/api/departments/${event.target.DepartmentId.value}`, {
        method: "PUT",
        headers:{
            "Accept":"application/json",
            "Content-Type":"application/json",
            "Origin": "*"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            Id: event.target.DepartmentId.value,
            Name: event.target.DepartmentName.value
        })
    })
    .then(res=>res.json())
    .then((result)=>
    {
        this.setState({snackbaropen: true, snackbarmsg: "Edited successfully!"})
        
    },
    (error) =>{
        this.setState({snackbaropen: true, snackbarmsg: "failed"})
    }
    )
}
```